# React - Refine - Display Json object correctly in form field

Tags: reactjs, json, refinejs

I have the following json object retrieved from the backend REST API.

```
{
    "id": "bb8dc1fa84d842bd82e3494f2d9b8e49_LATEST",
    "status": "publish",
    "version": "LATEST",
    "permission_document": {
        "Version": "2023-05-22",
        "Statement": ["*"],
        "Signature": "9434903948034389439843834900920-320-3-2024904209429049033490430--340"
    }
}
```

I want to display the attribute 'permission_document' in a React form field where the user should be able to edit some fields and then resubmit it to the backend.

Im using the Refine dashboard template: https://refine.dev/
And this is the front-end code for displaying the form:

```
import React from "react";
import { IResourceComponentsProps } from "@refinedev/core";

import { Edit, useForm, useFileUploadState } from "@refinedev/antd";

import { Form } from "antd";

import MDEditor from "@uiw/react-md-editor";

import { IPermissionDocument } from "interfaces";

export const PermissionDocumentEdit: React.FC<IResourceComponentsProps> = () => {
    
    const { formProps, saveButtonProps } = useForm<IPermissionDocument>();
    
    return (
        <Edit saveButtonProps={{ ...saveButtonProps }}>
            <Form {...formProps} layout="vertical">
                <Form.Item
                    label="Permission Document"
                    name="permission_document"                    
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                        },
                    ]}
                >

                <MDEditor 
                    id="permission_document" 
                    preview='edit' data-color-mode="light"                
                />
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </Edit>
    );
};
```

How to display the json as pretty json?
[Check here to see how it looks on the frond end and how it is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kySho.png)

I lack a little bit of frond end skills to find the solution for this problem

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to print the object inside the editor.
You have to transform your object in a string before displaying it, like this:

```
JSON.stringify(JSONobject, "", 2)
```

2 is the number of spaces for indentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have tried different variations of this. The text does get displayed but then I can not edit the content anymore. Am I missing something?
      `<MDEditor  defaultValue={JSON.stringify(queryResult?.data?.data.permission_document, null, 2)} value={JSON.stringify(queryResult?.data?.data.permission_document, null, 2)}>
                   
                    </MDEditor>`

Comment: you should pass the entire object to the MDEditor component so that you can edit that, and stringify only what you send to get displayed in the return statement of the MDEditor (after the edits), which i'm assuming it's what prints stuff in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im not getting there yet. Could you be a little bit more precise on how to do it? If not then Ill try to find a completely different approach to displaying it.